# MacOS: Dark Mode label rendering correctly in Interface Builder but incorrectly at runtime

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-darkmode

I have an NSViewController XIB that I am trying to adapt to Dark Mode. In Interface Builder, the label in question seems to change the text [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjtYN.png), however at runtime, the text is back to its [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwYCC.png). I do not modify the label in code at all.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: NSTextView have same bug but not consistent. Set default color in code works for textView. self.textView.textColor = [NSColor controlTextColor];

Comment: didn't work for me. Anyone else?!